# Setting batch size on scheduled apex with batch execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> results)

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have a scheduled batch that I need to adjust the batch size on.  I've seen articles where the batch size is managed in the batch class' execute() method, but only when the execute method is in the form

```
execute(SchedulableContext sc){
   Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(new batchClass(), batchSize);
}
```

I'm (currently) using the form

```
execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> results)
```

and then working with the results list, but then it appears that I have now lost the ability to control the batch size.  Is there a way to manage the system.schedule() statement to adjust the batch size?

Comment: `execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> results)` is the signature of the method you must implement due to Batchable interface. `Database.executeBatch(new batchClass(), batchSize);` is how you start a batch via Apex. They are not the same. `System.schedule(jobName, cronExpression, schedulableClass)` runs a class that implements `Schedulable`, so a class that must have `execute(SchedulableContext sc)` method. Just search for `Database.executeBatch` statement (it could have only one parameter) and add the scope size.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks @RubenDG!  It was in the schedulable class' execute() method, not the batch class'.